# Unable to load a certificate in Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, x509certificate, x509certificate2

I am developping an Azure Function which needs to load a certificate from a secured Base 64 string. The certificate is protected by a key. The certificate and the password are stored in an Azure Key Vault.

When I try to load the certificate from the Function, I get errors in both v1 and v2 Functions.

Here is the code used to load the certificate :

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(certificateBase64), certificatePassword)
```

With this code for .Net I have a strange issue I can reproduce locally. The issue is linked to .Net 4.6.1. In .Net Core 2.0, it works fine locally (in Azure Function CLI), but I got a strange issue regarding a file not found (https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/11042)

As mentionned at the end the previous post, I tried to the **X509KeyStorageFlags.EphemeralKeySet** flag.

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(certificateBase64), certificatePassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.EphemeralKeySet)
```

The flag is not yet available for .Net Core 2 (https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/24454), and not also in .Net 4.6.1, the framework used by Azure Functions.

Is there a way to force the Net Framework used by an Azure Function v1 ? Is there any **simple** workaround in .Net Core 2.0, wihtout storing the certificate as a file on the Function ?

Comment: Have you tried the approach outlined in this post? It is for app service but the same should be true of functions: https://msftplayground.com/2016/11/using-certificates-azure-app-services/

Comment: Hi Paul. Tried the solution described in the blog post, but the certificate could not be found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After many tries, I found a solution. The flag **X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet** must be used. It worked for both Function App V1 (.Net 4.6.1) and Function App V2 (.Net Core 2) :

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(certificateBase64), certificatePassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet)
```

Comment: I have literally been here all night trying to find this answer.... thank you! :D
(Still works Function App V4)